How to resolve a hanging query to a MS SQL database
I try to use python/pyodbc to insert data to a table:
import pyodbc
conn=pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
                    'Server=' + server + ';'
                    'Database=' + database + ';'
                    'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
cursor=conn.cursor()
query = f'insert into {table} (col1, col2) values (3, 4)'

cursor.execute(query)
conn.commit() # I forgot to add this

I forgot to add the commit step, then the table is hanging. If I run a select query from the table separately, the query is hanging. Is there anyway I can reset the table? I am also using the MS SQL Studio.

You're asking how to code something to cover for the thing you forgot to code?

are you sure that the connection was established, imho the are missing credentilas or integrated security in the connection string

When that process ends, the connection will be broken and the transaction abandoned.  It can't "lock up" your database.

Some connection allow for auto-commit (SQLAlchemy will give you an engine for this). Idle connections themselves will just age away. But nothing is going to commit that data without explicit instruction to do so, and a "cover-my-ass" approach to .commit() is frankly pretty bad

The thing is that any query on this table now is running for ever. I believe my code was causing this hanging. Is there any remedy? Such as a piece of code or certain operation on the database/table? This issue does go away after one or two days but I don't want to wait that long.
